# Modifying my function to count solutions of a puzzle

Tags: python, backtracking

I have a function that should solve a puzzle problem using backtracking. First I've built it to find a solution and return it and now I'm trying to count the number of all solutions possible for certain puzzle.

I used the same function that returns a single solution to continue and count all the solutions.

When I debug it, it shows me the counting but in the end, at some reason it doesn't return me the real count

This is my code:

```
def helper_solve_puzzle(picture,constraints_set,row,col,count,find_all):
    if check_constraints(picture, constraints_set) == 1 and is_full(picture):  # found a solution
        count[0] += 1
        if not find_all:
            return picture
    if type(index_validity(picture,row,col)) == tuple:
        row, col = index_validity(picture, row, col)  # check index is valid and update it if neccesery
        picture = paint_cell(picture,row,col) #paint a cell
        is_legal = check_constraints(picture,constraints_set)
        if is_legal == 0: #if the painted cell is a mistake, delete it anf go over the next cell
            picture = paint_cell(picture, row, col)
            return helper_solve_puzzle(picture,constraints_set,row,col+1,count,find_all)
        elif is_legal == 2: #if the painted cell is legal, mark it as "last changed" and go over for the next cell
            return helper_solve_puzzle(picture,constraints_set,row,col+1,count,find_all)
    elif not index_validity(picture,row,col): #if we made to the end and no solution found, change back the last changed cell and go over from there.
        row,col = find_last_changed(picture)
        if no_solution(picture):
            return count[0]
        picture = update_picture(picture,row, col)
        return helper_solve_puzzle(picture,constraints_set,row,col+1,count,find_all)
    return count[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when you modify and return a variable out of the scope. If you want to return the modified value of count you need to set it up inside the function scope.

```
def helper_solve_puzzle(picture,constraints_set,row,col,count,find_all):
    c = count[0].copy()
    ...

    return c
```

This way you will return the variable c, which is a copy of count[0] and you can modify it inside of the function scope and return it.

Comment: `count[0]` is an int. Can you say more about why copying it would help?

Comment: When you return something from the function you need to return something that is INSIDE the function. In the code you pasted, you were returning something that was outside the function. Capturing it as a copy, you can modify it in paralel, without modifing the original counter. In this way you will have an original counter and a modified one returned by the function.

It's a good practice to not modify things outside the function scope. Always return new ones which you can capture. In this case you will know what is failing in case you have bugs.

Comment: Another good practice is to have different names in the function parameters than your code outside the function. This will make the function more redeable and more universal, since it's not pointing to a variable from outside the scope.

Comment: ints are immutable though, so `.copy()` doesn't really serve a purpose. I would agree that the code is confusing - seems to me that it intends to mutate a `count` list which is shared across instantiations of the function: and in that case, the returns are unnecessary and confusing.